# Adding text to the beginning and end of a number of files?

Tags: linux, sed, text-editing

I have a number of files in a directory hierarchy. For each file, I'd like to add "abcdef" to the beginning, on its own line, and "ghijkl" to the end, on its own line. For example, if the files initially contained:

```
# one/foo.txt
apples
bananas

# two/three/bar.txt
coconuts
```

Then afterwards, I'd expect them to contain:

```
# one/foo.txt
abcdef
apples
bananas
ghijkl

# two/three/bar.txt
abcdef
coconuts
ghijkl
```

What's the best way to do this?

I've gotten as far as:

```
# put stuff at start of file
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/.../abcdef/g'

# put stuff at end of file
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/.../ghijkl/g'
```

but I can't seem to figure out how what to put in the ellipses.

Comment: I can’t help but notice how simple and straightforward this is in Windows: `for %i in (*) do echo abcdef>t.tmp & type "%i">>t.tmp & echo ghijkl>>t.tmp & move /y t.tmp "%i"` or alternately, `echo abcdef>header.tmp & echo ghijkl>footer.tmp & for %i in (*) do copy /y headert.tmp+"%i"+footer.tmp "%i" & del header.tmp & del footer.tmp`

Comment: @Synetech: Does that work recursively?

Comment: @Dennis, as in for files in subfolders? No, but you can add a `/r` to the `for` loop to make it recursive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a job for `sed`. To add lines, just use [I/O redirection](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).

For a single file named `filename`, you can do the following:

```
mv filename temp
(echo abcdef ; cat temp ; echo ghijkl) > filename
rm temp
```

To do this automatically to all files in the current directory, use `find` and `xargs`:

```
find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I % sh -c '
    mv "%" temp
    (echo abcdef ; cat temp ; echo ghijkl) > "%"
'
rm temp
```

Comment: I would suggest a tweak: `(echo abcdef; cat filename; echo ghijkl) > temp;  cp temp filename;  rm temp`, to retain attributes (owner and mode) on the files.

Comment: Ownership and permissions might get lost by simply moving the file. Good point, @Scott. But copying instead of moving might come with a great performance penalty (if the files are big), so I'd use `chmod` and `chown` with the `--reference` switch in this case.

Answer (score 2):

If you have GNU sed available you can use the `i\` and `a\` constructs:

Use line addresses to apply to first and last line respectively:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i -e '1i\abcdef' -e '$a\ghijkl'
```

Comment: To me this seems a more elegant, less error prone and more efficient solution than the one accepted.

Answer (score -1):

```
For files in directory as file
echo "abcde" && cat file && echo "fghijk" > file
```

Comment: This will not work for two reasons: 1. `cat` is not `echo`. It won't print `abcdef` but display an error. 2. Input file and output file cannot be the same.

Comment: This won't work either. It writes `fghijk` to `file` and deletes all the rest! It wouldn't work with parentheses either, since `cat`'s input and output file can't be identical.

Comment: Please do not just guess as to the solution for a problem. If you don't *know* the solution, take a moment to research (trying this yourself isn't too time-consuming in this case) or refrain from posting guesses.

Comment: Sorry I just got overly excited:P I'll try to control myself in future :D